# how to reproduce the same python hmac with base64 output in matlab

Tags: python, matlab, base64, hmacsha1

I have this python code snippet that create a signature

```
signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(self.__private_key, message_to_sign, sha).digest())
```

the ouput of the signature is **7WBwddbqe2BQEvLC20bwOFPt2fk=**

by running the debugger, i can see the message_to_sign and my private_key

[image]

My understanding is i should get the same result if i run the hmac function and then base64 encoding function but it shows different result as an example below:

if i set in matlab

```
msg= 'GET\n\n\nFri, 02 Mar 2018 16:31:09 +0000\n/api/annotation/5357434.json';
hash = HMAC(key,message,'SHA-1');
test = base64encode(hash);
```

test = **/svUNw1mx9nMndf7aXvQEUu+NkQ=**

the hmac function that i tried:

1. https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46182-hmac-hash-message-authentication-code-function
2. https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/34162/versions/1/previews/doHMAC_SHA1.m/index.html?access_key=

the base64:

1. https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39526-byte-encoding-utilities

python version: 2.7.13

matlab version: 2016a

How can i reproduce the same result from python?

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this question by using proper newline character which is char(10) instead of /n before.

```
message=['GET',char(10),char(10),char(10),'Fri, 02 Mar 2018 16:31:09 +0000',char(10),'/api/annotation/5357434.json'];
```